# Cast to base class and lose trace of inherited type

Tags: .net, vb.net

My Scenario:
I have a POCO model built out for Fluent+nHibernate that works fine when I create that object, User, and do any DB operations. I also have an inherited class called UserLocal that has a few extra properties used exclusively inside the application that the DB doesn't need. My base class is in a separate shared library so I don't want to add DB Ignored properties to it just for this one application and I'd rather not embed the base case as a property instead of inheriting, I want to use inheritance like I have it coded out but I'm running into one snag.

My Problem:
When I save the UserLocal to the DB I get "No persister for: AppNameSpace.Model.UserLocal". Well, that's fair so I tried casting to the base class first with `DirectCast(objUserLocal, User)` but I still get the same error. Through some online Q&A research I tried CType & DirectCast individually and going through an Object type first in all 4 combinations, ex: `CType(DirectCast(objUserLocal, Object), User)`.
I want to get rid of the fact that this is a UserLocal and retain my base class User but no matter what I try the type of the object is always UserLocal. I understand the desire for what it is doing and inheritance but this is a case where I want to defeat it, is this possible without creating a new User?

Comment: This is a mapping issue, not a casting issue. If you want the same table to hold both User and UserLocal instances, you need to define a Table-per-Hierarchy mapping. This assumes there *is* a database field that distinguishes between the two types, otherwise NH won't know which type to persist.

Comment: I don't want the table to hold the extra UserLocal properties in the DB though and I will not read UserLocal objects from the table either. From this application I want to save the base class only.